# making api request in php through ajax call in js file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to make an api request in my php file.
But my api request depends on the user's input which will be passed from the front-end.
And in order to do so, my front-end js file is making ajax call to the php file. But php file is keep returning null in its global variable, $_POST.

in function.js file, I have

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/model/validate.php",
data: data,
dataType: "JSON",
success: function(response){
console.log(response);
},
error: function(response){
console.log("Error: " + response);
}
});
```

and in my validation.php file i have

```
<? php
if(is_ajax()){
echo "ajax works"
}
function is_ajax() {
return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}
```

is_ajax is a helper function that checks if there was any ajax call.
So every time I run these files, I get error and i'm not sure why.
Once this is done, I plan to make api call using curl in my php file but for some reason, $_POST is always returning null. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the contents of `data`?  My guess is that the data is not sent as urlencoded data, but some other format such as JSON. In that case, the `$_POST` variable will be set to `null`, since PHP can only automatically parse urlencoded data.

Comment: Also, you're telling jQuery that you're expending a JSON object back, but your returning plain text. So jQuery will throw an error since it's not able to parse the response as JSON.

Comment: Just remove the `is_ajax` function and just echo `json_encode(array('status'=>'OK'));` When that works you can try getting all clever again

Comment: ok so on my php file, now it is echoing (json_encode("ajax works")) and data was just a json object. And how do i send data as urlencoded data? data is just javascript object @Frxstrem

Comment: If it is an object or you use `serialize()` it will be urlencoded by jQuery by default.

Comment: Either serialize the data in JS when you send it (and deserialize it into an object in PHP) or send it as standard `key=value` pairs. If you're posting a bunch of stuff to PHP that isn't `key=value` pairs, it won't work, because `$_POST` is an associative array, not a string. Even if you're serializing, it still needs to be sent under a key that you can read back in `$_POST`. If the key was "mydata", you'd then check `$_POST['my_data']`.